# Referencing Custom Settings in Row Level Formulas in Reports

Tags: reporting, formula

We have a Custom Setting field that contains a value which we update on a regular cadence.  With the release of Row Level Formulas on Reports we suddenly have several reports that need to reference this value in a Row Level Formula.

Instead of hard coding the value in these formulas and needing to update each of them every time the Custom Setting field is updated, I would prefer to reference the setting in the formula like I can when creating Formula fields.

Unfortunately I have not found any documentation referencing this nor found any way to do it while testing in a formula.

I have tried the following but gotten validation errors each time:

```
Custom_Setting__c.Field_Name__c

Setup.Custom_Setting__c.Field_Name__c

$Setup.Custom_Setting__c.Field_Name__c
```

My instinct is telling me that because Row Level Formulas are so new (and maybe considered beta? I forget) that this might not be rolled out yet.

Does anyone know if there is a way to reference a Custom Setting value from within a Row Level Formula?

A workaround would be to create a Formula field on the Objects that are being reported on that references the Setting, however I would prefer to not create a bunch of Formula Fields unless necessary.

Comment: Pretty sure if you want such a reference you need to migrate to `Custom Metadata`.

Comment: Custom Metadata doesn't seem to work either. I tried  `$Custommetadata.BaseMDT__mdt.BaseRec.ReportFactor__c` in an org where that object, record & field exist, and it didn't work - says the field doesn't exist, same as for Custom Settings.

Comment: Attributes of other global variables like `$User` and `$Organization` give the same error. So I think none of them are supported in row-level formulas. (Which are GA as of  [Winter '20](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_rd_reports_row_level_formulas.htm). But this should definitely be mentioned in the ["Tips, Limits & Limitations"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_limits.htm&type=5) article.

Comment: Thank's @ThomasTaylor for confirming my thoughts.  Hopefully Row Level Formulas will be fleshed out a bit and expanded upon as most SalesForce functionality eventually is but in the mean time this should definitely be added to the limits & limitations article as you said.  There is so much inconsistency with Formulas in their various contexts across SalesForce that it's always fun finding out what you can and can't do in certain places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off testing by myself and Thomas Taylor, neither Custom Settings or Custom Metadata values are accessible in Row Level Formulas at this time.

A workaround to referencing this data in a Row Level Formula is to create a Formula Field on the Object referenced in the Report that pulls the Custom Setting field or Custom Metadata field required.